# How to bind a Controller's method in each of the item in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div  uib-accordion-group class="panel-default"  template-url="group-template.html" ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.Data">

</div>
```

Look at the above code snippet. I want to bind a method like myCtrl.update() in each item in the ng-repeat. So that later in the directive's scope I can invoke the method like item.update().

Comment: what is the issue you facing in adding ` myCtrl.update() `?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to bind a method define in controller in each of the item in a ng-repeat in angularJS.

Comment: Can you elaborate the code little bit by providing code for myCtrl and group-template.html?

Comment: Just forget about the template thing. Think plainly. Is there any proper way to bind a controller's method to the scope of ng-repeat elements? This is my original question actually.@SiddheshPhatak

Comment: Do you want to bind method to `ng-click()`

Comment: Yes. I do. @Ved

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-bind for that purpose.

```
<div  uib-accordion-group class="panel-default"  template-url="group-template.html" ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.Data">

<span ng-bind="yourMethod(item.Data)"></span>

</div>
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it as you do binding outside ng-repeat.

```
 <div  uib-accordion-group class="panel-default"  template-url="group-template.html" ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.Data">
          <button ng-click="myCtrl.update()"></button>
    </div>
```